# Do roots of a polynomial with rational coefficients exist in conjugate pairs?

Tags: polynomials

I came across a question which said

> If a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $4$ with rational coefficients touches the x axis at $(\sqrt 2, 0)$, find the other two roots

The answer said that since the coefficients of the polynomial are rational the roots will be conjugate pairs. Now this isn't true for quadratic equations, but works when roots are irrational.
I don't know if a biquadratic polynomial is analogous to a quadratic, so can the same logic be applied here? Would the roots have not been conjugate pairs if the coefficients weren't rational?

Comment: Can you give some surrounding context for the problem?

Comment: The polynomial $x^2-2$ doesn't factor into a product of polynomials with rational coefficients and positive degrees. Since $x^2-2$ and your polynomial have a common factor of positive degree, that common factor must be $x^2-2$. Therefore, $-\sqrt{2}$ is another root.